# How to find out whether the page is mapped in RAM or not in Linux Kernel

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Given a struct page, Is there any function which gives the result whether the page is present in memory or not.

I am working on 32-bit ARM board, and i know all the pages of low memory will be always mapped and can be accessed directly, mainly interested to find out pages of high memory, if the page is not available then i can call kmap_atomic and map it, use it and then unmap it by calling kunmap_atomic.

Comment: See https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand005.html#sec:%20Pages

Comment: `kmap_atomic` does not pin the page into memory, but it *does* disable page faults (and disables preemption). You need to pin the page into memory *before* calling `kmap_atomic`, otherwise a page fault on the page would cause a crash.